# GetVstoObject fails with AccessViolationException

Tags: .net, excel, c#-4.0, vsto

I am developing an Excel Add-In in .NET 4.0 (C#) with Excel 2010 and VSTO 4.
In my Excel accessor class I have a property "CurrentWorkbook" that returns the VSTO extended active workbook:

```
public Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Workbook CurrentWorkbook
{
  get
  {
    if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook == null) return null;

    return Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook);
  }
}
```

Normally, this works fine. But there are situations, in which `GetVstoObject` fails with an `AccessViolationException`:

```
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.IHostItemFactoryNoMAF.CreateProvider(Object document)
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorkbookImpl.GetVstoObject(_Workbook workbook, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, UInt32 officeVersion)
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ApplicationFactoryImpl.GetVstoWorkbook(_Workbook workbook)
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ApplicationFactoryImpl.GetVstoObject(_Workbook workbook)
   at TNPExcelAddIn2.ConnectionLayer.ExcelAccess.ExcelAccessor.get_CurrentWorkbook()
```

Hint: 
In the error case `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook` is not `null`, but in the Debugger you can see that the underlying `Sytem.__ComObject` is somewhat "corrupt" because its `m_ObjectToDataMap` is `null`.

- Any guesses???
- How can I deal with this?
- Or how can I "test" the `System.__ComObject` before using `GetVstoObject`?

Thank's in advance for your answers,
Jörg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, it turns out, that the specific XLSX-Workbook was not OK, because there were corrupt graphic objects in the XLSX-ZIP-Container. Excel itself ignored this, but the VSTO layer seemed to have problems with it.

I ended up in using the following solution to catch the errors:

```
public Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Workbook CurrentWorkbook
{
  get
  {
    return GetVSTOWorkbookByInteropWorkbook(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook);
  }
}

[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
public static ExcelVSTO.Workbook GetVSTOWorkbookByInteropWorkbook(ExcelInterop.Workbook workbook)
{
    if (workbook == null) return null;

    try
    {
        return Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(workbook);
    }
    //This also catches unhandled "AccessViolationException" in the VSTO layer because 
    //we have decorated the method by the annotation [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions].
    catch (AccessViolationException ex)
    {
        //Handle exception...
    }
}
```

Hopes this helps others also,
Jörg